# asp.net convert utf-8 from webservice request

Tags: asp.net, string, utf-8

I get some string data from a webservice in utf-8. How do I convert it in an aspx vb to a readable format? The website is german.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is readable. ASP.NET should be able to read it just fine. If it's transmitted with a `Content-Type` whose `charset` parameter is set to something other than `UTF-8` you might need to instruct ASP.NET to force the decoding to UTF-8. Use Fiddler and figure out how the HTTP request looks like and pay special attention to the `Content-Type` parameter.

If you have a different output-encoding than UTF-8, you should still be able to output the characters correctly if you decode them with the correct encoding. What is your output encoding? What encoding is the web service you're communicating with using? Figure the answer to these questions (using Fiddler) and your solution should be obvious.